# Creating a sparse matrix in Matlab with a specified number of independent Bernoulli +-1 nonzero entries

Tags: matlab

How in Matlab we can form a matrix X, `1000 by 1000`, which is sparse with, say,

```
5% of independent Bernoulli +-1 nonzero entries?
```

I.e. such a matrix would have `rho = ||X||_0/10^6 = 0.05.`

Comment: Do you need that matrix to be `sparse` in [Matlab's sense](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly choose 5% of elements

```
n = numel(X);
ind = randi(n, round(.05*n), 1);
```

Assign these elements with random variable

```
X(ind) = binornd(1, .5, length(ind), 1) *2-1;
```

Check [`binornd`'s documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binornd.html) for more details.

To avoid duplicate `randi` numbers, you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) from the Statistics Toolbox, or something like `randperm` as mentioned in [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/149228), *or something like*

---

EDIT

```
ind = [];
t0 = round(.05*n);
t1 = length(ind);
while t1 < t0
    ind(end+1:t0) = randi(n, t0-t1, 1);
    ind = unique(ind);
    t1 = length(ind);
end
```

Comment: `rand(...)<.5` or `randi(2,...)-1` are probably faster than `binornd`

Comment: @LuisMendo Right. I just used it to address it's a Bernoulli rv.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build the matrix as [sparse (in Matlab's sense)](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html):

```
M = 1000; %// number of rows
N = 1000; %// number of columns
perc = 5/100; %// percentage (fraction) of +/-1 entries

n = round(M*N*perc); %// compute number of nonzero entries
nz = 2*(rand(1,n)<.5)-1; %// generate nonzero entries: +/-1 with .5 probability
ind = randsample(M*N,n); %// choose linear indices of nonzero entries
X = sparse(ind, 1 ,nz , M*N, 1, n); %// build matrix as linearized
X = reshape(X,M,N); %// put into shape
```